# Network Shared Drive

Tags: windows-server-2016

We have window server 2016. The server are configured as a domain.

I tried to explore in the disk management, but stuck after creating new volume for E (external hard disk). D is the existed network shared folder  access that are granted for users.

[image]

What do I need to do, to increase the storage size? Currently the storage size is 1.36TB and we are left with 240GB in the server.
[image]

How do I go about the configuration?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any RAID configuration in the server? (I assume and I hope so), However if you need more space you have to replace the disk (s), this depends on your eventual RAID configuration.

Comment: Yes we have it unde RAID. Wanted to extend the network shared folder but got lost on how to go about it as scared if the network will be down as user not able to access the file and server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean increasing the size of the D: Drive on your Server, making the size of the Network Drive the same as the D: Drive, or just increasing the Network drive capacity?

To increase the size of your D: Drive you need to know what kind of drive that is. If its a RAID you might be able to extend it but how will wary between type and manufacturer. If its just a drive you can replace it or make it a RAID through a physical controller (formates the drive!) or windows dynamic disks.

If you want to expand the size of your network storage, having multiple network drives will make your live easier as you can just move the network share to a newly installed drive.

Comment: Apparently our D drive is set to mirrored the L drive. L drive is the official shared folder that is being access through the network for the users. They had been granted with permission rights.